# Multiple SQL Server versions and Integration Services evaluation period has expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Initially, I have installed Enterprise Evaluation Edition and then we have installed licensed version Standard Edition 2017.

[image]

All our apps using SQLSTANDARD instance and backup maintenance jobs were running fine.

Suddenly, I have found that the jobs are failing with this error,

`Integration Services evaluation period has expired`

I ran,

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.syssubsystems
```

and it returns `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe`

I have also changed registry,

[image]

But still same error. The maintenance jobs created from licensed Standard Edition version.

I have tired of this and switch it to use https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Have you completely uninstalled the Enterprise instance?

Comment: No. Does this required?

Comment: If you believe you have migrated everything to Standard, it would be the next logical choice to eliminate potential causes for conflict; especially with the issue you're experiencing. If it were me, I'd remove the Enterprise instance. Then you know you're only dealing with Standard edition features.

Comment: The app is running on prod. Does removing an instance impact the server?

Comment: If you are certain none of your processes are using the Enterprise instance, it should not affect the Standard instance, outside of requiring a reboot at some time post-uninstall. However, you should schedule an outage window to be safe.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Thanks

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I have also changed registry,_ From which **old value** to which **new value**?

Comment: The value changed form 1 to 3